# Should a JCombobox have objects from back-end in MVC architecture?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jcombobox

When having an MVC architecture, in the View can my `JCombobox` have my own Objects, or should I use a String representation.
In my opinion this shouldn't be used :

```
private final JComboBox<MyObject> combobox;
```

The piece of code binds the View with the Model, because `MyObject` can be find in the back end.This would be my solution.

```
private final JComboBox<String> combobox;
```

In this case I should do some kind of mapping.
Should I use the second implementation, or should I have a different Object in the JCombobox?

Comment: In MVC, you can bind the model to the view by using model methods to populate the view.  The model is still independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a String that you want to display in a combo box then display the String.

If you have data from a custom object that you want to display then add your custom object to the model. In this case you will also need to create a custom renderer for the object in order to display the required property. You will also need to provide a custom `KeySelectionManager` so that selection of combo box items using the keyboard will still work.

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for examples of how you can implement this.